# How to find AWS Resource from endpoint URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to make sense of an undocumented project. I have an endpoint that looks like it's an AWS API gateway resource. Is there a way to find that resource via the identifier?

I have

```
https://XXXXXXXX.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/production/dothis
```

I have looked in the console at API Gateways in Ohio(us-east-2) at Stages and none of them have a stage endpoint with an XXXXXXX that matches this endpoint's id.

The endpoint is functioning - so it is somewhere out there for sure.

Is there some other AWS resource type that would end up with an endpoint URL like that?  Or is it more likely that I have the wrong AWS account/profile? Can I search on the CLI by the XXXXXX id?

Comment: I would check other availability zones in the same region on api gateway. eg. Virginia.

Comment: The api gateway endpoint can be from different account.

Comment: the easy way is raise a support ticket. AWS will tell you whether or not the URL is mapped to a resource in one of your accounts.

Comment: have you tried https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-resources.html by passing the API id?

Comment: @ArunK if you get a moment pls make an answer?

Comment: I cant think of a way other than raising a support ticket

Comment: @ArunK - no i meant an answer here rather than a comment so i can mark this as answered bc that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have been in a similar situation and we ended up raising a support ticket to find it. Please raise a support ticket with AWS. They will at least let you know whether the endpoint url is mapped to one of your AWS accounts.